# Vuejs don't show component in blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i want to understand why it :
[Vuejs work in a normal blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovFsB.png)
[and when i integer the same vuejs file in a blade file like this, it's doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWFCr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know your question isn't clear enough but let me guess,
the first problem in your may be in your layout that you don't add 
app.js
or add it in the header 
try to put it at the end of the body element 
before `@endsection`